# Bitnami Redmine stack Could not find multi_json-1.7.7 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine, bitnami

when starting the redmine app occurs that error:

```
[ 2013-06-19 16:19:44.6047 27657/7ffa929ca700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1888 ]: [Client 24] Cannot checkout session. An error occured while starting up the preloader.
Error page:
Could not find multi_json-1.7.7 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:212:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:73:in `preload_app'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:127:in `<module:App>'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:6:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/user/redmine-2.3.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

I'm not using rvm, only the redmine stack. I have install the gem by running

```
gem install multi_json -v '1.7.7'
bundle update
```

My `gem list` have the `multi_json` gem in version 1.7.7.

Including my Gemfile.lock file was deleted by me and then performed the bundle install.

My OS is Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `bundle install` perform `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`